# After a fresh VS2017 install, a new .NET Core Web app still generates 7 errors

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2017

When I first installed VS2017 RTM and tried to create a new .NET Core app, I got 7 errors and it didn't work. So following some advice from online I deleted all my .NET Core packages and VS2017. Then did a new VS2017 install after selecting the .NET Core workload.

I again then did the New Project steps for: Visual C# / .NET Core / ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) / Web Application.

This still  generates the 7 errors listed below. How can I fix this?

```
Error       Package System.Diagnostics.TraceSource 4.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package System.Diagnostics.TraceSource 4.0.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter 1.0.0 supports: netstandard1.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.1)             
Error       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.                
Error       Package System.Xml.XmlSerializer 4.0.11 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package System.Xml.XmlSerializer 4.0.11 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)
  - netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0)
  - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.                
Error       Package System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument 4.0.1 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error       Package System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml 4.1.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml 4.1.1 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)
  - netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0)
  - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)
```

The .csproj file is below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: can you include your csproj file in the question.

Comment: I have added the csproj file. But as a new user of SV2017 I have no idea what it means.

Comment: Is there a reason you are targeting netcoreapp1.0 and not netcoreapp1.1?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue. If possible, find another computer to try again.

Comment: Well netcoreapp1.0 seemed to be recommended over 1.1 which appeared to be more unstable. The dotnet CLI templates don't let you choose for reactrdux. Anyway I just installed the creators update today and went back to VS2017 for another try. Still got the 7 errors after loading the reactredux project, but then after a Build it compiled and ran, but bombed out with a null reference (JS speak). The error was: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'void' (I have to learn Typescript now). So I guess the dotnet new CLI framework examples have bugs too.